# If $\#A$ and $m$ are relatively prime, then $a\mapsto ma$ is automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is it true if $A$ is a finite, abelian group and $m$ is some integer relatively prime to the order of $A$, then the map $a\mapsto ma$ is an automorphism?

It's left as an exercise in some course notes, but I cannot verify it.

In particular it is used to prove that Hall complements exist for abelian Hall subgroups of finite groups.

Comment: What is $A{}{}$?

Comment: If you're talking about groups, then notice that the map $a \mapsto ma$ for some integer $m$ is in general only a homomorphism if $A$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: since $\gcd(m,\#A)=1$, you can find an integer $d$ such that $dm\equiv1\pmod{\#A}$. Show that the map $a \mapsto da$ is the inverse of $a \mapsto ma$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To prove injectivity (and therefore surjectivity), suppose that $ma=mb$.  Then $m(a-b)=0$. So $a-b$ has order a factor of $|m|$. But the order of $a-b$ must divide the cardinality $\# A$ of $A$.  Since $m$ and $\#A$ are relatively prime, it follows that $a-b$ has order $1$, that is, $a-b=0$.

Comment: That's injectivity.

Comment: Yes. I was leaving a hint that probably left one step too many to do.  So I have changed the wording.

Comment: You may assume $b=0$ and therefore simplify the proof (injective <-> kernel zero).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\rm\:n = |A|.\:$ By Lagrange and Bezout, $\rm\: na, m\,a= 0\:\Rightarrow\: (n,m)a = 0.\:$ Here $\rm\:(n,m) = 1.$